# How to pick any symbol name (string) and modify it in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I was searching to pick up the symbol name of any crypto pair (example BTCUSDT )and convert it into into USDT_BTC for sending the name for automation purpose. This is basically String Manipulation Framework in pine script.

Answer (score 1):

after searching and doing some work i found out that this can be done in pine script version 4.
First i saved the symbol name in the variable 'a' using `syminfo.ticker` which returned me the crypto symbol name (eg. BTCUSDT ) , then i took the USDT using `f_strRight(_str, _n)`. I used another function `f_strReplace(_src)` to remove USDT (last four chars) from the string and added both of them `tostring(f_strRight(a, 4))+'_'+tostring(f_strReplace(a))` to get (eg. USDT_BTC)

```
// instrument's symbol and exchange.
a= syminfo.ticker
// ————— Function returning the rightmost `_n` characters in `_str`.
f_strRight(_str, _n) =>
    // string _str: source string.
    // int    _n  : number of rightmost characters to return.
    string[] _chars = str.split(_str, "")
    int _len = array.size(_chars)
    int _beg = max(0, _len - _n)
    string[] _substr = array.new_string(0)
    if _beg < _len
        _substr := array.slice(_chars, _beg, _len)
    string _return = array.join(_substr, "")


// ————— Function that replaces a character at position `_pos` in the `_src` string with the `_str` character or string.
f_strReplace(_src)=>    // Thx to @LonesomeTheBlue.
    // string _src  : source string.
    // int    _pos  : position of character to be replaced. The first character's position is 0.
    // string _str  : replacement character or string.
    string[] _chars = str.split(_src, "")
    string[] _str =array.new_string()
    int _len = array.size(_chars)
    for i=0 to _len-5
        array.insert(_str, i, array.get(_chars,i))
        
    string _return = array.join(_str, "")
    
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(x=bar_index + 2, y=hl2, style=label.style_label_upper_left,
         color=color.new(color.yellow, 70), textcolor=color.black,
         size=size.large, text="This instrument trades at\n" + 
             syminfo.prefix + " with Following symbol passing to the alert message:\n" + 
             tostring(f_strRight(a, 4))+'_'+tostring(f_strReplace(a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your particular example can be done easier, with the help of the built-in variables in the `syminfo.` namespace:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
str = syminfo.currency + "_" + syminfo.basecurrency
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(bar_index, high, text = str)
```

I recommend checking out Pine v5, it has a bunch of new string-related functions in the `str.` namespace that do the same thing but built-in and without arrays (so, faster and more universal).

Comment: Thanks, that's much better and easier to implement. But it will not be able to pick up desired string for symbols like ADAUPUSDT, it is returning USDT_ADA which will trigger alert in wrong symbol. for the "ADAUPUSDT" it should be returning "USDT_ADAUP". Let me know if we can update the above code to get the desired result.